# How do I properly switch with enums in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I'm having trouble understanding how enums work in C#, since they print their own "name" rather than the value they represents. As an example I want to translate a weekday to another language using enums. These represents the day of the week.

```
enum Weekdays { Mon = 1, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun };
```

My following method is the problem. If I don't have the (int)-casts on each of the cases, it will not compile due to type differences(?).

```
// Returns weekday in Norwegian.
private static string translateWeekday(int nummer)
{
    switch (nummer)
    {
        case (int)Weekdays.Mon:
            return "Mandag";
        /* ...... */
        case (int)Weekdays.Sun:
            return "Søndag";
    }
    return "Invalid input.";
}
```

I test my program with this. I also have to cast this one.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ukedag = translateWeekday((int)Weekdays.Tue);
    Console.WriteLine(ukedag);
}
```

My actual question now is why do I need these casts and why doesn't C# print out the values, but the names of each enum if I try to print them out? And in my example, how should I do it properly (i.e. not have to use casts 7 times in a switch, which seems unnecessary)?

Comment: _"why doesn't C# print out the values, but the names of each enum if I try to print them out"_ because your method `translateWeekday` returns `"Mandag"` or `"Søndag"` instead of the int value.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?  What do you want your input to be and what do you want your output to be?

Comment: Enums don't "represent" a value. They are value types that can be cast to integers, unlike C/C++ where an enum is more or less an alias for its value. The value of `Mon` *is* Mon as far as C# is concerned (kind-of).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant that C# prints out **Mon** and not **1** if you run `Console.WriteLine(Weekdays.Mon);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change

```
private static string translateWeekday(int nummer)
```

to

```
private static string translateWeekday(Weekdays nummer)
```

and remove all the casts.

> why doesn't C# print out the values, but the names of each enum if I try to print them out?

An enum is a type that has a special `ToString` that, by default, "prints" the name of the value instead of the value.

From [Enum.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx)

> and (if) there is a named constant equal to the value of this instance, then the return value is a string containing the name of the constant

You can use the `.ToString("d")` to print the "value" of an enum.

```
string str1 = Weekdays.Mon.ToString(); // Mon
string str2 = Weekdays.Mon.ToString("d"); // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName( DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek )` to get the localized(in your case norwegian) day-name. So no need for your `Weekdays`-enum since there is already the [`DayOfWeek`-enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can even specify the culture you want to use explicitly:

```
var norwegianCulture = new CultureInfo("nn-NO");
string dayName = norwegianCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek); // torsdag
dayName = norwegianCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DayOfWeek.Monday); //måndag
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't/don't want to change the parameter type, you can do the cast earlier:

```
switch ((Weekdays)nummer)
{
    case Weekdays.Mon:
        return "Mandag";
    /* ...... */
    case Weekdays.Sun:
        return "Søndag";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually, in such cases, decorate the enumeration values with the 'DescriptionAttribute' found in the System.ComponentModel namespace, providing the required textual description and I have the following extension method that returns the text specified for the corresponding enumeration value:

```
public static string Description(this Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) 
                                                as DescriptionAttribute;

    if (descriptionAttribute == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(descriptionAttribute.Description))
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    return descriptionAttribute.Description;
}
```

So in your case you can define the enumeration as:

```
enum Weekdays
    {
        [Description("Mandag")]
        Mon = 1,
        [Description("Søndag")]
        Sun, 
    }
```

and then write

```
 Weekdays today = Weekdays.Mon;
 Console.WriteLine(today.Description());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /// <summary>
  /// An enum class of days
  /// </summary>
  public enum Days
  {
    Sunday= 0,
    Monday= 1,
    Tuesday= 2,
    Wednesday=3,
    Thursday=4,
    Friday= 5,
    Saturday= 6
  }
```

The enum class

```
switch (type)
      {
        case 0:
          return Days.Sunday.ToString();
        case 1:
          return Days.Monday.ToString();
        case 2:
          return Days.Tuesday.ToString();
        case 3:
          return Days.Wednesday.ToString();
        case 4:
          return Days.Thursday.ToString();
        case 5:
          return Days.Friday.ToString();
        case 6:
          return Days.Saturday.ToString();
        default:
          return string.Empty;
       }
```

There is also a way to use descriptors above the enum values, so you can just call .Description and get the string representation of the value.